# Exceptions to no private API usage in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

My company is looking to develop an iOS application which would need to make use of private APIs to function - in fact use of such APIs is the entire basis of the program (I'm purposely not revealing details for business reasons).

My question is, is there any chance that if we explained the situation, that Apple would allow an exception for our app to be approved even when using these private APIs? I believe we have a very legitimate reason to request an exception for the functionality we're looking for, so I'd just like some examples of any exceptions that have been made to the private APIs rule with details so that we can have a better idea of what might be expected from Apple. Thanks.

Comment: Are you certain that there is no other way to achieve what you want than using private APIs?  You might try asking here to see if there is an alternative you have not considered.

Comment: The only explicit exception that I am aware of was for Google.  Others were allowed to slip by temporarily, but were later made a reason for rejection after they opened up a new API for everybody (which may happen to your desired APIs if you ask Apple and give them a great reason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be honest with you: no. If you're looking to put this on the app store, no.

You may wonder how I know this with such certainty: I've worked with carriers that *carry* the iPhone, and I've worked with very large companies with whom Apple has working relationships (ie, you can actually talk to someone fairly senior at Apple). If Apple won't let carriers use private APIs, they not going to let you do it either. One 'legitimate' private API use might be to put recent call information into a carrier provided account app. Could be pretty useful, right? And the carrier already has this information, so no problem? No. It's a big problem. Apple just won't allow it. You have to get it from elsewhere (ie, via the carrier's own database).

There are no exceptions, and currently apps get statically analysed *immediately* after submission. If you call a private API your app will almost certainly be instantly rejected automatically by the static analyzer. It won't even go through manual review.

If you're looking to distribute on the app store, there are literally *no exceptions* now that code gets statically analyzed.

Put it another way: if Apple made an exception for your app they'd have to make an exception for *every* app. And then your unique selling point wouldn't be so unique any more.

Sorry I can't give you a more positive answer, but I speak from experience!

Comment: There are some who can get exceptions, but it's very difficult.

That said, You could also try fooling the static analyzer using NSInvocation and nsstrings.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could get an exception to the static analysis, and I've worked on apps for some large corporations where we *have* got exceptions (to the content rules), although it's certainly possible. Is this from your own experience?

Comment: yes, it's from my own experience but I don't want to elaborate

Answer (score 4):

Its entirely possible, but extremely unlikely. they made an exception for UIGetScreenImage(); but that was because there was a very large number of developers who had filed radars for it.

I would suggest you file high quality radars for enhancement, explaining what you want and why. also maybe consider using a DTS to find out if there is an alternative way, or if they are able to get authorisation for it.

Comment: Even `UIGetScreenImage()` was made private again after public APIs were introduced that replicated most (but not all) of its functionality.  Filing enhancement requests, getting others to file duplicates of those requests, and hoping for the best in upcoming versions is the best way to proceed.  Apple rarely makes exceptions to rules like this, and even then it tends to only be for specific companies like Google.

Comment: UIGetScreenImage was indeed made private again, once the main function was brought into public API. Enhancement requests with lots of helpful info and information about intent are the way forward.  This brings another good point, even if they allow you an exception in this release, don't be surprised if the next version is rejected.